# Unhook a function within a class in the child theme

Tags: customization, actions, child-theme

I am using Hestia theme and I want to unhook the function that displays footer copyrights to replace it with my custom function, I tried the `remove_action()` in my child theme functions.php but it didn't work.

Here is the file that contains the bottom footer action in the parent theme:
`hestia/inc/views/main/class-hestia-footer.php`

```
class Hestia_Footer extends Hestia_Abstract_Main {

    /**
     * Initialization of the feature.
     */
    public function init() {
        add_action( 'hestia_do_footer', array( $this, 'the_footer_content' ) );
        add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', array( $this, 'modify_footer_menu_classes' ) );
        add_action( 'hestia_do_bottom_footer_content', array( $this, 'bottom_footer_content' ) );
    }
.
.
.
public function bottom_footer_content() {
        $hestia_general_credits = get_theme_mod(
            'hestia_general_credits',
            sprintf(
                /* translators: %1$s is Theme Name, %2$s is WordPress */
                esc_html__( '%1$s | Powered by %2$s', 'hestia' ),
                sprintf(
                    /* translators: %s is Theme name */
                    '<a href="https://themeisle.com/themes/hestia/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">%s</a>',
                    esc_html__( 'Hestia', 'hestia' )
                ),
                /* translators: %1$s is URL, %2$s is WordPress */
                sprintf(
                    '<a href="%1$s" rel="nofollow">%2$s</a>',
                    esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org', 'hestia' ) ),
                    esc_html__( 'WordPress', 'hestia' )
                )
            )
        );
```

Here is the functions.php file in the child theme:

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_footer_copyright_action' );
function remove_footer_copyright_action() {
    remove_action( 'hestia_do_bottom_footer_content', array( 'Hestia_Footer' , 'bottom_footer_content' ) );
}
```

I also tried to instanciate the class containing the action in the parent theme, it didn't work either. Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

```
$Hestia_footer_object = new Hestia_Footer();

add_action( 'init', 'remove_footer_copyright_action' );
function remove_footer_copyright_action() {
    echo "test";
    remove_action( 'hestia_do_bottom_footer_content', array( $Hestia_footer_object , 'bottom_footer_content' ) );
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to search around for the different ways users have come up with to remove class initiated hooks. Here's a [git that may help](https://github.com/herewithme/wp-filters-extras/).

Comment: To remove the actions you can't create a new instance of `Hestia_Footer`, you need to use the same instance that the parent theme did. If the parent theme put it in a global variable you can use that. If it didn't, then you can't remove the action with `remove_action()`.

Comment: I don't think there is an instance in the parent theme, what should I use if I can't use remove_action() ? @JacobPeattie

Comment: You probably can't really do anything. The only workarounds are hacky and based on the specific structure of hooks as of right now, and they're subject to change. You should be contacting the theme author if you have questions about customising it.